# JOIN two DataFrames and replace Column values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have dataframe df1:

```
    Expenses        Calendar    Actual
0   xyz             2020-01-01  10
1   xyz             2020-02-01  99
2   txn vol(new)    2020-01-01  5
3   txn vol(new)    2020-02-01  20
4   txn vol(tenu)   2020-01-01  30
5   txn vol(tenu)   2020-02-01  40
```

Second Dataframe df2:

```
    Expenses    Calendar    Actual
0   txn vol(new)    2020-01-01  23
1   txn vol(new)    2020-02-01  32
2   txn vol(tenu)   2020-01-01  60
```

Now I wanted to read all data from df1, and join on df2 with Expenses + Calendar, then replace actual value in df1 from df2.

Expected output is:

```
    Expenses        Calendar    Actual
0   xyz             2020-01-01  10
1   xyz             2020-02-01  99
2   txn vol(new)    2020-01-01  23
3   txn vol(new)    2020-02-01  32
4   txn vol(tenu)   2020-01-01  60
5   txn vol(tenu)   2020-02-01  40
```

I am using below code

```
cols_to_replace = ['Actual']
df1.loc[df1.set_index(['Calendar','Expenses']).index.isin(df2.set_index(['Calendar','Expenses']).index), cols_to_replace] = df2.loc[df2.set_index(['Calendar','Expenses']).index.isin(df1.set_index(['Calendar','Expenses']).index),cols_to_replace].values
```

It is working when I have small data in df1. When it has (10K records), updates are happening with wrong values. df1 has 10K records, and df2 has 150 records.
Could anyone please suggest how to resolve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your solution correctly, it seems to assume that (1) the `Calendar`-`Expenses` combinations are unique and (2) that their occurrences in both dataframes are aligned (same order)? I suspect that (2) isn't actually the case?

Another option - `.merge()` is fine! - could be:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(["Expenses", "Calendar"])
df2 = df2.set_index(["Expenses", "Calendar"])
df1.loc[list(set(df1.index).intersection(df2.index)), "Actual"] = df2["Actual"]
df2 = df2.reset_index()  # If the original df2 is still needed
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, your assumptions are correct. It is possible that df1 has Nulls in Actuals. However df2 never has Nulls in Actual. With your approach, I am getting below error  when executing the df1.loc[df3.index, "Actual"] = df3["Actual"] 
Error:  "MultiIndex(levels=[['txn vol(new)', 'txn vol(tenu)'], ['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-04-01']],\n           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [2, 3, 2, 3]],\n           names=['Expenses', 'Calendar']) not in index"

Comment: @SK15 Could you add a sample to the question that replicates the error?

Comment: @SK15 I have a hunch what could be the problem: Not all `Expenses`-`Calendar` combination in `df2` are also in `df1`. See the adjusted answer.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it, using pd.merge

```
df=df.merge(df2,
        on=['Expenses', 'Calendar'],
        how='left',
        suffixes=('_x', None)).ffill(axis=1).drop(columns='Actual_x')
df['Actual']=df['Actual'].astype(int)
df
```

```
Expenses              Calendar  Actual
0   xyz             2020-01-01      10
1   xyz             2020-02-01      99
2   txn vol(new)    2020-01-01      23
3   txn vol(new)    2020-02-01      32
4   txn vol(tenu)   2020-01-01      60
5   txn vol(tenu)   2020-02-01      40
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am still getting incorrect results. For non-matched records, I am getting date in Actual column. I think this is because of ffill

Comment: @SK15, solution matched the expected result. If you don;t need actual for unmatched (unlike your posted question and expected result) then remove the ffill. i can help and better understand based on the data posted and expected result. hope response helps

Comment: @Naveed From my understanding `Actual_x` can have `NaN`s, so the `.ffill()` is propagating the `Calendar` values in this cases. If you remove the `.ffill(axis=1).drop(columns='Actual_x')` part, and add a new line `df.loc[df["Actual"].isna(), "Actual"] = df["Actual_x"]` this should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks Timus. It is working as expected after removing .ffill(axis=1).drop(columns='Actual_x') and adding df.loc[df["Actual"].isna(), "Actual"] = df["Actual_x"].

Comment: @SK15, did this solution worked for you?